# Задача на вложенные циклы

Tags: c

Вычислить сумму (`i` от одного до `n`) произведения (`j` от одного до `m`) 1 / (i^2 + j^2)`

```
int main() {
   int i, j, m, n;
   double s = 0, p = 1;
   scanf_s("%d%d", &n, &m);

   for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
         p *= (((double) 1. )/ ( j * j + i * i));
      }

   {
     s += p;
     p = 1;
   }

   printf_s("%lf", s);
   printf_s("\n");
   system("pause");
}
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Для проверки:
если n = 3, m = 4, то S = 0,00070148315736551;
если n = 4, m = 3, то S = 0,01246807440925088;
У меня выдает нули(0.000..)

Comment: У вас несколько действий происходит вне цикла. И зачем постоянно умножать `p`?

Comment: Простите, не до конца написал условие.

Comment: Уже правильное форматирование кода само по себе делает очевидными некоторые ошибки. А если бы автор не валил все объявления переменных в начало функции, а придерживался золотого правила объявлять переменные настолько локально, насколько это возможно, то ошибка была бы невозможна в принципе.

Comment: Не совсем очевидно. Новичок так сказать.

Comment: В чем вы видите смысл явного приведения типа `(double) 1.`??? После того, как вы добавили точку после `1`, у вас и так получилась константа типа `double`. Нет никакой необходимости еще и дополнительно приводить ее к типу `double`.

Comment: @bo_, Вы не правильно используете фигурные скобки. Если в 1 цикле нужно использовать несколько действий (помимо 2 цикла) то все действия нужно заключить как раз в эти скобки. А у вас циклы отдельно, суммирование отдельно от цикла. Посмотрите примеры в интернете, как делают вложенные циклы, на любом языке.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, ошибка, прежде всего, в том, что вы не поставили фигурные скобки для внешнего цикла, в результате чего его тело состоит только из одной операции - внутреннего цикла. Остальные операции по прибавлению суммы уже НЕ в цикле:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
         p *= (((double) 1. )/ ( j * j + i * i));
      }
--- > В этом месте оба цикла уже не работают <---
   {
     s += p;
     p = 1;
   }
```

Можно было бы исправить это, правильно ПЕРЕставив нужную скобку:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // <--- ВОТ ЭТА СКОБКА
  for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
    p *= (((double) 1. )/ ( j * j + i * i));
  }   
  s += p;
  p = 1;
}
```

Однако этот код кажется правильным, но всё ещё очень неудачный с точки зрения чуть более опытного кодера. Инициализацию промежуточного произведения `p` следует сделать ПЕРЕД тем, как вы будете это `p` начинать накапливать, аналогично с `s` (в начале функции `main` нужно инициализацию `p` и `s` убрать, ещё я бы убрал объявление `s` и `p` оттуда и перенёс сюда):

```
double s = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // <--- ВОТ ЭТА СКОБКА
  double p = 1;
  for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
    p *= (((double) 1. )/ ( j * j + i * i));
  }   
  s += p;
}
```

Далее видим, что произведение `i*i` будет каждый раз вычисляться в цикле заново, хотя его можно вычислить один раз (хотя вообще-то умный компилятор сделает это сам, но не каждый компилятор это умеет), заодно уберём лишнее приведение типов `(double)1`:

```
double s = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // <--- ВОТ ЭТА СКОБКА  
  double i2=i*i, p=1;
  for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
    p *= 1.0 / (j*j + i2);
  }   
  s += p;
}
```

Это уже почти то что нужно. Однако если говорить честно, то я бы внешний цикл перевернул задом наперёд, чтобы суммирование выполнялось от меньших членов суммы к большим, так результат может стать более точным. Но это уже тонкости, и если вдаваться в них, то придётся вообще всю теорию плавающей арифметики пересказывать.